# Troubles with Wifi and ethernet Aspire One AO725

Tags: debian, wifi, ethernet

I'm use Debian wheezy on a Acer Aspire One AO725. It has the following kernels:

```
3.2.0.4-amd64
3.7-trunk-amd64
```

The command `lscpi | grep Network`:

> 02:00:0 Network controller: Atheros Comunications Inc. AR9485 Wireless
>   Network Adapter (rev 01)

The computer must have the following settings (IP Static):

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.68
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Some times the computer works  fine with WIFI, in other times not works WIFI and Ethernet (with the same settings). What happened?

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Does both the WIFI and Ethernet work and then not work or is it just the WIFI?

Comment: What happens is that I have configured the wifi stops working and configure the ethernet (turn off the wifi), but now it does not work.